Pitch accent of Japanese nominal verbs with する
An odakagata word has its accent on its last mora but this is actually cancelled, unless followed by a particle or copula. This is the premise but I bumped into some nominal verbs such as "返事 する" where "henji", which is odaka, has a true pitch fall when followed by "suru". Does this means that "suru" can start the "sleeping" accent of the odaka nouns?

する attaches onto two character 漢語名詞 words following the PA of the original noun. So 返事する would be ヘンジ↓する.
This only applies to two kanji 漢語名詞. For more info see  愛する pitch accent confusion or I can give further information if you want more rules for する attachments.

I read the interesting  link you advised to me but it concerns two kanj  with up to two moras

I read the interesting  link you advised to me but the final accent of the compound verb can be either heiban or nakadaka with focus on すmora. No option for accent on final mora of the 2-kanji-2 mora  noun. Could it be becouse 1) henji is actually 2,-kanji/3mora noun or 2) because there is an omitted をwhich cancels the compound and restores the original accent of both nouns?

Sorry I'm having trouble understanding your English it's a bit all over the place what is your question exactly?

The rules are a bit complex because it depends on mora, number of kanji, and whether it's a 漢語名詞 or 和語名詞. But to answer your question for 返事 specifically, 返事 is a 漢語名詞 that is two kanji long. In this case REGARDLESS of mora count the original PA of the noun is used for attaching する which means the PA is ヘンジ↓する (返事する). The link is just there to provide more rules since in some cases the mora count does matter.

Thanks. It's all clear
